# Change style with php

Tags: php, html, css

is it possible to change css style with php? 
I got a H1 with a class, and an if statement. and if the statement is true I want the h1 to have the css : display:none. 
Is it possible, or do i have to use jQuery also ?

Comment: Is javascript a real issue?

Comment: Yes it is! Good luck ;D

Comment: Ok. A quick search on SO shows hundreds, literally, of the same question. FIRST link on Google is this: http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

Comment: @JonasNoerr, if your project is simple (like changing the css on click), I'd really recommend using jQuery instead of PHP.

Answer (score 3):

`<h1 style="<?php echo ($statement) ? 'display:none' : ''; ?>">HEADING</h1>`

But you need to know this is executed on server.

Comment: Additionally, I believe CSS files themselves can be named with the .php extension and gain the ability to use PHP.

Comment: Yes, but you would need to add this at the beggining of the file:
    `<?php header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8"); ?>`